# ¿Cómo puedo posicionar (Maquetar) un div con flexbox al final del documento?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, scss, css-grid-layout

Quiero ubicar mi etiqueta `footer` al finalizar el documento también el `sidebar` deberia llegar hasta el final del documento,pero no logro hacerlo, me queda un espacio en blanco cuando el contenido de alguna página es escaso.

Estoy usando `Grid` para ubicar (maquetar) las etiquetas `HTML` en determinadas posiciones.
La etiqueta `<main></main>` es donde se encuentra el contenido de mí página web; esta debería cubrir ese espacio en blanco y empujar los otros divs (footer y sidebar) hacia abajo.

## CodeSandox app

https://lnbno.csb.app/

## CodeSanbox Codigo

https://codesandbox.io/s/problema-lnbno?file=/src/App.js

## Imagenes para aclarar mi punto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Clase Grid con la que estoy maquetando:

```
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 55px auto 100px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "h h h h a"
    "c c c c a"
    "f f f f a";
  aside {
    grid-area: a;
  }
  header {
    grid-area: h;
  }
  main {
    grid-area: c;
    background-color: green;
  }
  footer {
    grid-area: f;
    background-color: purple;
  }
}
```

#### Todo el css

```
// DOCUMENT RESET 
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
  ul {
    list-style: none;
  }
}

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5 {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  border: solid 15px red;
}

// DOCUMENT STRUCTURE
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 1920px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 55px auto 100px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "h h h h a"
    "c c c c a"
    "f f f f a";
  aside {
    grid-area: a;
  }
  header {
    grid-area: h;
  }
  main {
    grid-area: c;
    background-color: green;
  }
  footer {
    grid-area: f;
    background-color: purple;
  }
}

.wrapper-closed {
  grid-template-areas:
    "h h h h h"
    "c c c c c"
    "f f f f f";
}

.sidebar-closed {
  display: none;
}


// NAVBAR
.navbar {
  height: 55px;
  // border-bottom: 2px solid #3c4043;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #565d64;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: #0360bd;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  // padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;

  nav {
    margin: {
      left: 50px;
      right: 50px;
    }
    ul {
      list-style: none;
      display: flex;
      li {
        margin: 6px;
        /* unvisited link */
        a {
          color: #fff;
          text-decoration: none;
        }

        /* visited link */
        a:visited {
          color: #fff;
        }

        /* mouse over link */
        a:hover {
          color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
        }

        /* selected link */
        a:active {
          color: #fff;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


// SIDEBAR
.sidebar {
  background-color: salmon;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  // right: 0px;
  // top: 0px;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  ul {
    background-color: salmon;
    text-align: left;
    li {
      a {
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 65px;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-left: 30px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);

        transition: all 0.4s ease;
        i {
          //margin-right: 40px;
        }
        &:hover {
          padding-left: 50px;
        }
        &:active {
        }
      }
      i {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import "normalize-css";
import "./main.scss";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
// Views
import Home from "./views/Home";
import PageA from "./views/PageA";
import PageB from "./views/PageB";

export default function App() {
  const [menuIsOpen, setMenuIsOpen] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className={menuIsOpen ? "wrapper" : "wrapper wrapper-closed"}>
      <aside>
        <Sidebar menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen} setMenuIsOpen={setMenuIsOpen} />
      </aside>
      <header>
        <Navbar menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen} setMenuIsOpen={setMenuIsOpen} />
      </header>
      <main>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/a" element={<PageA />} />
          <Route path="/b" element={<PageB />} />
        </Routes>
      </main>
      <footer>FOOTER</footer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Navbar

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Navbar = function ({ setMenuIsOpen, menuIsOpen }) {
  const handleToggle = function () {
    setMenuIsOpen(!menuIsOpen);
  };
  return (
    <div className="navbar">
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleToggle}>
          <i className="fas fa-bars">Ocular / Mostar Sidebar</i>
        </button>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link className="Button" to="/">
              <i className="fas fa-home space-i">/Home</i>
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link className="Button" to="/a">
              <i className="fas fa-home space-i">/Page A</i>
            </Link>
          </li>

          <li>
            <Link className="Button" to="/b">
              <i className="fas fa-home space-i">/Page B</i>
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Navbar;
```

#### Sidebar

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Sidebar = function ({ menuIsOpen, setMenuIsOpen }) {
  return (
    <div className={menuIsOpen ? "sidebar" : "sidebar sidebar-closed"}>
      <div className="name">
        <p>User Name Here</p>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">
            <i className="fas fa-home space-i">/Home</i>
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/a">
            <i className="fas fa-home space-i">/Page A</i>
          </Link>
        </li>

        <li>
          <Link to="/b">
            <i className="fas fa-home space-i">/Page B</i>
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

#### Home

```
const Home = function () {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="box">
        <div className="box-title">
          <h1>Home</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="box-body">
          A mythic and emotionally charged hero's journey, "Dune" tells the
          story of Paul Atreides, a brilliant and gifted young man born into a
          <div className="buttons-right">
            <button className="btn">Ver</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default Home;
```

PD: No sé como subir mi código ejecutable en esta plataforma, por eso lo subí a codesanbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hola solo es un problema de los tamaños pues yo lo solucione dándole un height a tu main, con eso el sabe cuanto espacio puede ocupar en la pantalla y de está manera quedaría tu main.

```
main {
    grid-area: c;
    background-color: green;
    height: 69vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes darle `1fr` a tu etiqueta donde se encuentra tu contenido.

**Ejemplo:**

```css
:root {
  --header-color: #0360bd;
  --footer-color: #800080;
  --content-color: #008000;
  --aside-color: #fa8072;
}

body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

.header {
  background-color: var(--header-color);
  height: 60px;
}

.content {
  background-color: var(--content-color);
}

.footer {
  background-color: var(--footer-color);
  height: 80px;
}

.aside {
  background-color: var(--aside-color);
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <header class="header">header</header>
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <footer class="footer">footer</footer>
  </div>
  <aside class="aside">aside</aside>
</div>
```